# In Windows 10 Hyper-v i removed Ubuntu instance, but one hardrive is still not removed. How to re-add back ubuntu instance?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

In Windows 10 Hyper-v I removed the Ubuntu instance, but one hard drive is still not removed. How do you re-add the Ubuntu instance?
What settings do I need to use to re-add the drive of installation I accidentally removed, but one file is still here Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.vhdx